# Question in Algorithmic Trading / Indicator / Understanding the constant

Tags: python, constants, moving-average, algorithmic-trading, indicator

I was reading a code which is able to give you out the data points in stock prices, where you should buy or sell the stock.

Basically it is using a moving average method, where when the 30 days moving average is crossing the 100 days moving average, this is seen as a buy signal and vice versa.

How does that flag indicator work in this code? What does it exactly do during the execution? I know it should indicate when both are crossing, but I have problems to understand how it is even changing, when it was set as a constant initially and there are no more further operators with the flag variable?

```
def buy_sell(data):
    signalPriceBuy = []
    signalPriceSell = []
    flag = -1
    
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if data["SMA30"][i] > data["SMA100"][i]:
            if flag != 1:
                signalPriceBuy.append(data["AAPL"][i])
                signalPriceSell.append(np.nan)
                flag = 1
    

      
            else:
                signalPriceBuy.append(np.nan)
                signalPriceSell.append(np.nan)
                
        elif data["SMA30"][i] < data["SMA100"][i]:
            if flag !=0:
                signalPriceBuy.append(np.nan)
                signalPriceSell.append(data["AAPL"][i])
                flag = 0
            else:
                signalPriceBuy.append(np.nan)
                signalPriceSell.append(np.nan)
        else:
            signalPriceBuy.append(np.nan)
            signalPriceSell.append(np.nan)
    return(signalPriceBuy, signalPriceSell)
```

Comment: *"there are no more further operators with the flag variable"* - I see `flag = 1` and `flag = 0` in the code you've posted.

Comment: Yes, but how does flag change from -1 to a 1 for example?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking - it changes to `1` by being assigned on the line I mentioned above. I'd recommend a structured tutorial (see https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F) to get the language basics, and running the code through http://www.pythontutor.com/ to understand the control flow.

Comment: thank you, i think i now got it, i basically was not understanding the logic behind it, but after looking at it more thoroughly i understood it! Thanks for that first comment, you just sometimes become blind to see the basic stuff when you look for too long at sth and make it more complicated than it actually is!